# Pic c mp lab errors at build point

Tags: c, pic, microchip, mplab

i am very new to micro controller world. i am using pic16f877, making simple calculator using lcd and keypad. 
i am getting following errors at build time. kindly help me out.

```
Build C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Calculator for device 16F877
Using driver C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-Lite\9.50\bin\picl.exe

Make: The target "C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Main.obj" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-Lite\9.50\bin\picl.exe" -C C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Main.c -q --chip=16F877 -P --runtime=default --opt=default -D__DEBUG=1 -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" 
Warning [176] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Includes.h; 24.0 missing newline
Error   [141] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\LCD.c; 6.18 can't open include file "delay.h": No such file or directory
Make: The target "C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Keypad.obj" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-Lite\9.50\bin\picl.exe" -C C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Keypad.c -q --chip=16F877 -P --runtime=default --opt=default -D__DEBUG=1 -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" 
Warning [176] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Includes.h; 24.0 missing newline
Error   [141] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\LCD.c; 6.18 can't open include file "delay.h": No such file or directory
Make: The target "C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\LCD.obj" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\HI-TECH Software\PICC-Lite\9.50\bin\picl.exe" -C C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\LCD.c -q --chip=16F877 -P --runtime=default --opt=default -D__DEBUG=1 -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s" 
Warning [176] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\Includes.h; 24.0 missing newline
Error   [141] C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic\LCD.c; 6.18 can't open include file "delay.h": No such file or directory

********** Build failed! **********
```

Comment: Looks like it's not finding the `delay.h` header. Have you checked if it exists?

Comment: yes it exists in header folder but still same error

Comment: Try googling "picc lite warning 176". Or you could add "Includes.h" to the question.

Comment: includes.h already exist

Comment: What version of MPLAB are you using? You may need to add the path.

Comment: v8.91 version i am using.what about path?

Comment: And what happens if you copy `delay.h` into the folder `C:\Users\RXN\Desktop\pic` ?

Comment: according to some of the error messages, the includes.h file is missing a <cr> 'carriage return' at the end of the file.  Simply open the file in an editor, scroll to the end of the file, click the 'enter' button on your keyboard, save the file.  Then, to avoid such problems in the future, modify your editor so a carriage return is always assured at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

From the menu bar open 'Project'->'Build options...'->'Projects'. Under the 'Directories' tab choose 'Include Search Path' from the drop down menu. Then click 'New' and the '...' button on the right. Navigate to your the directory that the header is in and click 'OK'.

Alternatively, try putting the full path to header in the c file.